# Why is hover working in IE11, but not in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I have got a problem using the hover element in my css file.
It is working in IE11, but not in Chrome. 
This is the code that i am using for hover:

```
.datagrid table thead th:hover {background-color:#baeafd;}
```

The whole css file:

```
.datagrid table { border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; width: 100%; } 
.datagrid {font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #8C8C8C; }
.datagrid table td, 
.datagrid table th { padding: 5px 10px; }
.datagrid table thead th {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #EDEDED), color-stop(1, #8F8F8F) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #EDEDED 5%, #8F8F8F 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#EDEDED', endColorstr='#8F8F8F');background-color:#EDEDED; color:#000000; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; border-left: 1px solid #919191; }
.datagrid table thead th:first-child { border: none; }
.datagrid table thead th:hover {background-color:#baeafd;}
.datagrid table tbody td { color: #000000; border-left: 1px solid #DBDBDB;font-size: 12px;border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;font-weight: normal; }
.datagrid table tbody .alt td { background: #fff; color: #000000; }
.datagrid table tbody td:first-child { border-left: none; }
.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none; }
```

My html code:

```
<div class="datagrid"><table class="sortable">
<thead><tr><th>Numbers</th><th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr class="alt"><td>5</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>10</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="alt"><td>9</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change background-color to background

```
.datagrid table thead th:hover {background:#baeafd;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/prq4zvjf/1/

I don't think it should have been working on IE11.
I changed `background-color` to `background`

```
.datagrid table thead th:hover {background:#baeafd;}
```

You had `background` declared on the original `th` element but you were trying to substitute `background-color` on the hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `background` properties to `th` element.. so You'll have to change the specific properties for the hover effect to be visible..

Try this css..

```
.datagrid table thead th:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #8F8F8F), color-stop(1, #EDEDED) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #8F8F8F 5%, #EDEDED 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8F8F8F', endColorstr='#EDEDED');
}
```